# Laravel: Layouts.master not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I built the demosite in Laravel, but I got the following error:

> ErrorException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [layouts.master]
>   not found.(View:
>   /var/www/html/project/laravel/laravel/resources/views/page.blade.php)

The master.blade.php is next to the page.blade.php, both are in resources/views

master.blade.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
        This is the master sidebar.
        @show
        <div class="container">
        @section('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

page.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@yield('title', 'Page Title')
@section('sidebar')
@parent
<p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@endsection
@section('content')
<h2>{{$name}}</h2>
<p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

What goes wrong? I working from [this tutorial.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_tutorial.pdf)

Comment: do you have `layouts` folder and `master` file inside this folder ?

Comment: No they are next to each other. I putted in a layouts folder, and now any error, but $name variable don't get any value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
@extends('master')
```

They are both at the `views` root you said. Or create a directory called `layouts` and place `master.blade.php` inside.

**Updates**
In your `master.blade.php` where you want your `content` to be "injected", do:

```
@yield('content')
//remove @section('content') because your master does not extends any other layout
```

The exact same way you did with `@yield('title')`.

Comment: Now it loads the page, but the $name variable don't have any value. (In the turorial they add a value in the route (Route::get('blade', function () {
return view('page',array('name' => 'Test'));});)

Comment: THen add the value like they did and the `$name` will appear.

Comment: I added it "Route::get('blade', function () { return view('page',array('name' => 'Anonymous'));});"
The tutorial says that in this case the word Anonymous should appear

Comment: Ok just so we are clear, what you are asking about now has nothing to do with your original answer and the solution that fixed it, but I have provided an update to my original that will help with your second question. If it helps, please mark the answer. :) thanks

Answer (score 5):

When you are using `@extends('layouts.master')` means your view searches for the `master` layout under `resources/views/layouts` directory.

So make sure the `master` layout exist under the `resources/views/layouts` directory.

Answer (score 0):

By following the above answers, you should have your @extends pointing at the correct folder but are you looking at the correct `Route::get()`? You need to create a route that goes to this new `.blade` template, not the `master.blade.php` in order to see the `@yield(***)`.